# How to reset a value when a particular column changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to re-sequence some records in my database. I came up with this script:

```
UPDATE r
SET r.DisplaySequence = temp.DisplaySequence
FROM    
    SomeTable r JOIN
    (
        SELECT RecordID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DisplaySequence, InsertedOn) AS DisplaySequence
        FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE FacCode IS NULL AND UserID IS NULL
    ) AS temp ON temp.RecordID = r.RecordID 
WHERE FacCode IS NULL AND UserID IS NULL
```

This will update the `DisplaySequence` column with new values and respect any order that current records might have.

However, I need to "reset" the `DisplaySequence` whenever the `RecordCategoryID` changes.

So if I have this data:

```
RecordID | RecordCategoryID | DisplaySequence
---------------------------------------------
   1            1                  1
   2            1                  2
   3            1                  3
   4            2                  4
   5            2                  5
   6            2                  6
```

The `DisplaySequence` should restart from 1 for those last 3 records, since the `RecordCategoryID` changed, but I can't figure out how to "reset" the `ROW_NUMBER()` value while doing this?

Comment: use `partition by` in your row_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James Z answered in his comment:

using the `partition by` part of the `over()` clause for **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**

```
UPDATE r
SET r.DisplaySequence = temp.DisplaySequence
FROM SomeTable r 
  JOIN (
        SELECT RecordID
        , row_number() over (
          partition by RecordCategoryId
          order BY DisplaySequence, InsertedOn
          ) AS DisplaySequence
        FROM dbo.SomeTable 
        WHERE FacCode IS NULL 
          AND UserID IS NULL
    ) AS temp ON temp.RecordID = r.RecordID 
WHERE FacCode IS NULL 
  AND UserID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the example; this worked. Will accept once I can